# How to make a face the same scale as another?

Tags: modeling, transforms, faces, selection-tools

I have this face:
[image]

I want to make it the same scale as another face:
[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: Where is that other face you are talking about?

Comment: It's exactly where I highlighted.
not only this face, how can I make a face as big as another face? how's that possible?

Comment: I'm sorry but you didn't highlight a face at all.

Comment: The answer is probably "use Vertex Snapping" like here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/246037/78972

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're trying to ask is easier to see in wire frame view:

[image: wire frame view]

I believe you're asking to make the upper selected circle have the same diameter as the lower selected circle; or possibly to inset the upper face so that the inset face has the same diameter as the inner circle.

In the first case you can do it by scaling the upper circle.  In the second case you can use the inset tool (shortcut <kbd>I</kbd>).

Here are two ways to do this, using the inset tool, as it shows the process more clearly.  The first way is imprecise and relies on your eye.  The second way requires math; but it's not hard math.

### By Eye

- Go to wireframe mode.
- Select only the top face.
- Align your view so that the two surfaces are parallel to each other and the camera.  In this case, the orientation means that top view will do.
- Type <kbd>I</kbd> and drag the mouse until the inset lies as close to directly above the bottom circle as possible.  You should end up with something like this:

[image: face inset to match]

tip:  Before you start the inset, arrange for the face to be in the center of the viewport, and zoom in until it nearly fills the screen.  Use the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when dragging the mouse when you are near the right position to give fine control over the mouse.

### By math

- Go to the Viewport Overlays dropdown menu and enable "Edge Length"

[image: edge length]

- Highlight one of the radial edges between the two bottom circles:

[image: image showing edge length]

- Select only the top circle.
- Use the value you got from the measurement above as an input to the inset.  I got 0.197 for my example, so I type <kbd>I</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>7</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

The calculation for scaling the face down is a bit harder so I leave it as an exercise.  Basically you need to scale by the ratio between the diameters of the two circles in this case.

The downside is that this approach has to be adapted to each geometry situation.  The eye approach won't work if the faces aren't parallel; the math approach needs to be modified if they're not circular.